# Underline content of a VStack

Tags: swiftui

I’m trying to add an line at the bottom of a `VStack` that fills to width of the `VStack` which is determined by the other content in the `VStack`, but the `Rectangle` I am using fills up the available space of the entire view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Testing123")
            Rectangle().frame(height: 2)
         }
    }
}
```

[image: problem image]

How can I make the `Rectangle` only have the width necessary for the `VStack` to fit its content?

Comment: I think you can make what you want with `.background` or `.overlay` of `VStack`. Those width are affected by the width of `VStack` so you can put the line on it with some extra code that is related to an alignment element such as `.frame` or `VStack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

Put your `Rectangle` in an `.overlay()` of the `VStack`.  Put the rectangle in its own `VStack` and use a `Spacer` to push the `Rectangle` to the bottom.  Control the spacing between the rectangle and your original `VStack` by adding `.padding` to the last view in the `VStack`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hi")
            Text("Testing123")
            Text("Bye").padding(.bottom, 10)
        }
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Rectangle().frame(height: 2)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

---

[image: example running on simulator]